# cannot connect to driver error in tomcat while running deployment.

Tags: postgresql, tomcat

I hope someone may help me out soon.. I am able to run my app completely fine on localhost however unfortunately as i deploy a war file onto the tomcat and try run it, it keeps giving me following error. 
As i mentioned, I am able to connect to the db (not my localhost but db on the server) and get a REST response out too just fine, i do not understand why am i getting this error.
Yes i have all the hibernate and postgres jar files and added maven dependencies still tomcat is having a hard time running the driver. please help!

Error log:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to     create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

type Exception report

message org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create     requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:419)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
careers.nebula.ben.db.repository.signup.UserRepo.<init>(UserRepo.java:18)
careers.nebula.ben.service.signup.UserInformation.getPrimaryUserInfo(UserInformation.java:44)
careers.nebula.ben.iws.signup.UserInformationIWS.locateUserById(UserInformationIWS.java:38)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    root cause

    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
careers.nebula.ben.db.repository.signup.UserRepo.<init>(UserRepo.java:18)
careers.nebula.ben.service.signup.UserInformation.getPrimaryUserInfo(UserInformation.java:44)
careers.nebula.ben.iws.signup.UserInformationIWS.locateUserById(UserInformationIWS.java:38)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280)
org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:407)
org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:275)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
careers.nebula.ben.db.repository.signup.UserRepo.<init>(UserRepo.java:18)
careers.nebula.ben.service.signup.UserInformation.getPrimaryUserInfo(UserInformation.java:44)
careers.nebula.ben.iws.signup.UserInformationIWS.locateUserById(UserInformationIWS.java:38)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:64)
org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:150)
org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:407)
org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:275)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
careers.nebula.ben.db.repository.signup.UserRepo.<init>(UserRepo.java:18)
careers.nebula.ben.service.signup.UserInformation.getPrimaryUserInfo(UserInformation.java:44)
careers.nebula.ben.iws.signup.UserInformationIWS.locateUserById(UserInformationIWS.java:38)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu) logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: The error log shows "connect timed out".  It seems you have to check your connectivity from the tomcat server machine to the db server machine and make sure the db server is configured to accept connections from the tomcat server.

Comment: Hi Gleen, may you please explain on that. So I have here is rest - hibernate - postgres as my stack. Running on my local; rest is giving me the the correct json being pulled from the postgres table. i deployed my app onto a cloud server which also has the db on it (once successful connected via local) and this error stacks comes up.. i read is through so it through a hibernate exep, then postgres driver exep and finally times out when fe doesnt hear anything from be. my best guess is my app server is missing the postgres driver? hmm.. advice lol@Glenn

Comment: It is finding the driver, otherwise you would have a "ClassNotFound" exception. Hibernate is trying to make the connection to the database but failing on the connect: "Error calling Driver#connect". It is using the Postgresql driver because: "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed." But it ultimately fails because it is not getting a response from the db server: "connect timed out". Can't really debug through comments, but you need to verify that the db server is running, accepting connections, and is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i ran into the solution myself, so obviously this may vary for different users but however since i was connecting from local i was using an external ip address to connect to the db server however while i deploy the app onto tomcat server i was running into this exception. solution; i just had to change my hibernate.cfg.xml from external to internal ip address and everything worked fine.